# Show that $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$, category of presheaves for $\mathbb{C}$, is cartesian closed

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma, cartesian-closed-categories

So I want to show that $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$, which is the category of presheaves for $\mathbb{C}$ ([$\mathbb{C}^{\mathrm{op}} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$]), is cartesian closed. Using the Yoneda lemma and adjunction, I define $F^G$, for presheaves $F$ and $G$ as follows.
$$
  F^G(C)
  \cong \operatorname{Hom}(y(C), F^G)
  \cong \operatorname{Hom}(y(C) \times G, F) \,.
$$
So I will just define, $F^G(C) = \operatorname{Hom}(y(C)\times G, F)$.

But I made a mess checking this definition works; unless there is a easier way, I would have to define an $\varepsilon$, evaluation map and then check that it satisfy the required universal property.

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: What is $\hat{\Bbb C}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have convinced yourself that $\operatorname{Hom}(y(C) \times G, F)$ is indeed a presheaf, then we have by construction (and the Yoneda lemma) a natural bijection:
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(y(C), F^G) \cong F^G(C) = \operatorname{Hom}(y(C) \times G, F).
$$
This is almost the universal property for the exponential object, we just need an arbitrary presheaf $Z$ in place of $y(C)$. Since every presheaf is a colimit of representables, there is functor $D: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $Z$ is the colimit of $yD: \mathbb{D} \to \hat{\mathbb{C}}$. Arrows $Z \to F^G$ correspond naturally to cocones on $yD$ with vertex $F^G$. Such cocones consist of arrows $y(C) \to F^G$, so by the above natural bijection this corresponds to cocones with vertex $F$ on the diagram
$$
\mathbb{D} \xrightarrow{D} \mathbb{C} \xrightarrow{y} \hat{\mathbb{C}} \xrightarrow{(-) \times G} \hat{\mathbb{C}}.
$$
Another basic fact about presheaves is that the functor $(-) \times G$ preserves colimits. So the colimit of the above diagram is $Z \times G$. So cocones with vertex $F$ on the above diagram correspond to arrows $Z \times G \to F$. We thus see that
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(Z, F^G) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(Z \times G, F),
$$
which is the defining property of the exponential object.

Comment: I get the gist of the proof. But 1 thing that is bothering me is that where did we make use of the explicit definition of $F^G$. I mean ultimately it's about checking this definition works, but the above argument on first sight seemed a bit general.

Comment: @user16319 The first natural bijection uses the definition of $F^G$. From that bijection, everything follows. The idea is that that bijection only work for representables (by definition), and we wish to extend it to every presheaf. The argument is then that we can do this by using that every presheaf is a colimit of representables.